# Create a grayscale image from (32-bit floating point) values in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, bmp, grayscale, pgm

With Java, a grayscale image from an array with (32-bit floating point) values. Could I use BMP or PGM? What its the best image format with no compression for this array with these (32-bit floating point) values?

Answer (score 2):

There's a variant of PGM called [PFM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pfm.html)  (in `Pf` mode for grayscale) that supports IEEE 32 bit floating point samples.

You could also store these images in an uncompressed [TIFF](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/faq.html#q1) file too. I'm not sure what software does support floating point TIFFs though, as this is certainly outside of "Baseline" TIFF.

BMP is not suitable for floating point.

I have a Java ImageIO plugin that reads [PFM](http://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/#netpbm-portable-any-map-pnm-31), and it's not too hard to extend it to write I guess. If your task is to implement read/write yourself, I'd certainly choose the PFM format, for simplicity.

I also have a TIFF plugin (available on the same link), but it doesn't support floating point sample format (TIFF sample format `3`) yet. Feel free to [propose such a feature](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues), and supply a few sample images for test purposes.